# Implement a template function that iterates over collection

Tags: c++, oop, vector

***How do I implement this template function which in future selects the fast vehicles by iterating over the collection that is provided?***

> `void select(T test, std::list<const Vehicle*>& vehicles)`: a
> **template** function that iterates over the vehicles stored in the `m_vehicles`, and adds to the second parameter all vehicles for which
> the `test` is true. The first parameter (`test`) can be a lambda
> expression, a pointer to a function, or a functor that matches the
> prototype:
> `bool func(const sdds::Vehicle*);`

**This is one of the lambda expressions that is going to be called in order to select fast vehicles only**

```
auto fastVehicles = [&](const sdds::Vehicle* veh_fast){
            bool value = false;
            
            if (veh_fast->topSpeed() > 300){
                value = true;
            }
            
            return value;
};
```

**My function is not working, however, this is the class and what I have tried so far:**

```
class Autoshop {
    
    std::vector<Vehicle*> m_vehicles;
    
public:
   
    Autoshop();
    ~Autoshop();
    Autoshop& operator +=(Vehicle* theVehicle);
    void display(std::ostream& out) const;
    
   template<typename T>
    void select(T test, std::list<const Vehicle*>& vehicles){
        bool c = true;
        if (test == c) {
             for (auto it = m_vehicles.begin(); it != m_vehicles.end(); ++it) {
  vehicles.push_back(*it);
                
             }
        }
    }
};
```

***Errors:***

> error: no match for call to '(main(int, char**)::<lambda(const
> sdds::Vehicle*)>) ()'    46 |         if (test() == c) {
> |             ~~~~^~ w6_p2.cpp:80:29: note: candidate: 'main(int, char**)::<lambda(const sdds::Vehicle*)>'    80 |
> auto fastVehicles = [&](const sdds::Vehicle* veh_fast){
> |                             ^ w6_p2.cpp:80:29: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

Comment: For you information: there is [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) that can be used: `std::copy_if (m_vehicles.begin(), m_vehicles.end(), std::back_inserter(vehicles), test);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to test a vehicle, so you have to pass a vehicle to the test function.

So the call to `test` should be inside your loop, not outside, and you pass the dereferenced iterator to it. I.e.

```
for (auto it = m_vehicles.begin(); it != m_vehicles.end(); ++it)
    if (test(*it)) // perform the test on a vehicle
        vehicles.push_back(*it);
```

A range based loop might be slightly easier to understand

```
for (auto vp : m_vehicles)
    if (test(vp)) // perform the test on a vehicle
        vehicles.push_back(vp);
```

Or use `std::copy_if` as suggested in the comments above.